# PHP WMI not working after windows update

Tags: php, windows-10

I am running PHP and Apache 2.4 on my test machine under Windows 10 Pro. After the last windows update my COM commands in PHP are no longer returning any variables. This is frustrating because I am using them to monitor usage statistics and uptime in a script. Heres the code I am using (that worked up until the last update):

```
public function get_server_system_info() {
    if (stristr(PHP_OS, 'win')) {
        $wmi = new COM("Winmgmts://");
        $server = $wmi->execquery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");
        $info = array();
        foreach($server as $i) {
            $info['systemstatus'][] = $i->Status;
        }
        if($info) {
            return $info;
        } else {
            die("Unable to load query.");
        }
    }
}
```

I use a similar function for some other information I pull from the system, all of which stopped working as well. I have narrowed it down to the `execquery` is returning null for all my values, but that shouldn't be possible since northing about the configuration of the system has changed, it just had a windows 10 update. Did they change the names of the commands and I am unaware? Thanks

Comment: Is your WMI service running? [`net start winmgmt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826517(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes i checked that first to make sure. Is there any way to query it outside of php to see if its responding there and its just a php fault?

Comment: Ok, good. Yes, there is a tool: [`wmic`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181088.aspx). Try that.

Comment: Okay I am getting Alias not found with this command `wmic:root\cli>SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk` with this error `SELECT - Alias not found.`. Any command I enter says Alias not found.

Comment: In PowerShell, try: `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | select *`. That has an interface more like what you're expecting. In `wmic`, you don't use WQL directly, you'd do just: [`logicaldisk`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/).

Comment: `Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "Win32_LogicalDisk"` It's like the `Win32_Processor` and `Win32_LogicalDisk` Ityems aren't even avail;able now. I checked using the `wbemtest` command with CMD and those object classes are no longer in the list of items...

Comment: I know this is a little late, but did you ever figure this out? I updated windows as well and suddenly none of my scripts or batch files are working, and everything I have is local- it's not even on a server. I just keep getting errors along the lines of "No input file specified." It's not my htaccess because these are software programs that worked just fine perhaps two weeks ago.

Comment: I couldn’t solve the issue no. The WMI is missing the local_32 options I need